# C++ #define or typedef and functions?

Tags: c++, performance

Although #define and typedefs can be used to get to the same results, I was wondering if one of these options is more elegant or faster than the other. Is there any reason why I should prefer typedefs and functions over #define?

```
#define unt uint32_t

#define msin(x) std::sin(x)

namespace LL {
typedef uint32_t unt;

float sin(float x) {
    return std::sin(x);
}
}  // namespace LL
```

Comment: *"why I should prefer typedefs and functions over #define"* Type safety, ability to put them in specific scopes (namespaces, etc) and thus no obscure name conflicts.

Comment: They most certainly do not accomplish the same results. In all but the smallest of programs, using macros as you do is bound to start causing issues.

Comment: For types, I recommend "using". For constants I recommend declaring a const value of the correct type, like "const int MAX_VALUE 5", which results in type safe, debuggable but still performant code.

Comment: none of the two! if you want to call `std::sin(x)` you should write `std::sin(x)`. anything else is evil obfuscation and should be avoided. If this is just because your example is simplified, then the example is simplified too much

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if one of these options is ... faster

Neither typedef nor macro is faster as far as runtime is considered. Maybe in theory one may be faster to compile, but probably in an insignificant way.

Function is unlikely to be any slower as long as it is expanded inline.

> I was wondering if one of these options is more elegant

The typedef and function are more elegant. Always use them instead of a macros. They are regular identifier and follows namespace rules. Macros are not affected by namespace.

Function like macros are especially problematic and their arguments do not behave like beginners would expect them to behave. Furthermore, error messages will much more understandable with functions.

But also consider whether a typedef or a wrapper function is necessary in the first place. It can often be counter productive to obfuscate the underlying type or function.

---

Macros are useful for: header guards (if you dislike #pragma once) , repetitive declarations (some may dislike this use case), cross system porting (for example for feature detection and system specific attributes)